Do non-Muslims have protected places of worship but face restrictions on propagating their religion in a Muslim country?
Is the following statement correct?
Non-Muslims and their places of worship are protected under a Covenant in a Muslim land, but they are not allowed to propagate their religion in a Muslim Country.

It is correct, although simplified.
Places of worship:
If the area is at war then the non-Muslim's places of worship are not protected.
If the area is under Islamic rule and came under Islamic rule by a treaty then preexisting places of worship are protected, however new places of worship can not be constructed.
If the area was conquered by force then the places of worship are not protected, it is the choice of the Muslims to allow the non-Muslims to retain them or to demolish or convert them, although some madhabs hold that it is obligatory to remove them since they are now part of Muslim's property.
See What is the ruling on non-Muslims having Temples, Churches and Synagogues in Muslim lands? and Does Hagia Sophia belong to Muslims? for details.
Freedom to practice religion:
Non-Muslims who are Dhimmis are allowed to remain on their religion in private. However in public matters Islamic law applies to them.

قاتلوا الذين لا يؤمنون ... حتى يعطوا الجزية عن يد وهم صاغرون
Fight those who do not believe ... until they pay jizyah with their own hands while they are subdued
— Quran 9:29
الصغار هو جريان أحكام الإسلام عليهم
Being subdued means the imposition of the laws of Islam upon them
— Tafsir al-Baghawy

Part of this is that they can not 'openly' do anything which is forbidden in Islam, they can not propagate their religion as that is inviting towards kufr and leading others astray which is forbidden by Islam.
Further, propagation of their religion will inevitably involve criticism of Islam. Allowing them to do that is empowering kufr and the opposite of subduing and humbling them which is required as per verse 9:29.
Criticism of Islam is incompatible with having a treaty:

وإن نكثوا أيمانهم من بعد عهدهم وطعنوا في دينكم فقاتلوا أئمة الكفر إنهم لا أيمان لهم لعلهم ينتهون
But if they violate their oaths after their covenant, and attack your religion with disapproval and criticism, then fight the leaders of disbelief  - for surely their oaths are nothing to them - so that they may stop.
— Quran 9:12

Ref: Ahkaam Ahl al-Dhimmah
